# Iterating over std::optional

Tags: c++, option-type, stdoptional

I tried to iterate over an `std::optional`:

```
for (auto x : optionalValue)
{
    ...
}
```

With the expectation of it doing nothing if `optionalValue` is empty but doing one iteration if there is a value within, like it would work in Haskell (which arguably made `std::optional` trendy):

```
forM optionalValue
( \x ->
    ...
)
```

Why can't I iterate an optional? Is there another more standard C++ method to do this?

Comment: `if (optionalValue) { ....}` ?

Comment: What about `if(optionalValue)` like it is intended to use :D

Comment: you should post a [mcve] and the error message. The error message should contain enough information to answer the "why not?". And reading the docs can answer the second question

Comment: sorry, but the question reads like "I wish C++ would work differently. Why does it not work the way I wish?"

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Let's assume it was `if (auto optionalValue = computation())`. The fact that I need to dereference `optionalValue` after this feels like an extra mental burden (I have to remind myself that I don't need to check again whether it has a value).

Comment: It looks like what you need is [`views::maybe`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1255r7.html), but it shouldn't be C++23, C++26 might adopt it.

Comment: fwiw a `std::vector<T>` can also hold either 1 or 0 elements and you can iterate it (though in contrast to `std::optional` it uses dynamic allocations)

Comment: @yairchu I just updated my answer to include another way to get even closer to what you wanted (see "Alternative 2"). But do consider if you actually need this.

Comment: [the `views::maybe` proposal's newest spec](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p1255r10.pdf) includes a "`views::nullable` which adapts nullable types—such as `std::optional` or pointer to object types—into a range of the underlying type"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::optional` does not have a `begin()` and `end()` pair. So you cannot range-based-for over it. Instead just use an `if` conditional.

*See Alternative 2 for the closest thing to what you want to do.*

Edit: If you have a temporary from a call result you don't have to check it explicitly:

```
if (auto const opt = function_call()) {
  do_smth(*opt);
}
```

The check for `static_cast<bool>(opt)` is done implicitly by `if`.

---

**Alternative 1**

Another alternative is to not use an `std::optional<T>` but `std::variant<std::monostate, T>`. You can then either use the `overloaded` idiom or create a custom type to handle the monostate:

```
template <typename F>
struct MaybeDo {
  F f;

  void operator()(std::monostate) const {}
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T const& t) const { f(t); }
};
```

which will allow you to visit the value with some function:

```
std::variant<std::monostate, int> const opt = 7;
std::visit(MaybeDo{[](int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }}, opt);
```

---

*Alternative 2*

You can also wrap optional in a thing that allows you to iterate over it. Idea:

```
template <typename T>
struct IterateOpt {
  std::optional<T> const& opt;
  
  struct It {
    std::optional<T> const* p;
    It& operator++() {
      p = nullptr;
      return *this;
    }
    It operator++(int) {
      return It{nullptr};
    }
    auto const& operator*() const { **p; }
  };
  auto begin() const {
    if (opt) return It{&opt};
    else end();
  }
  auto end() const {
    return It{nullptr};
  }
};
```

This is a crude sketch of how to do this and probably requires some love to work on different situations (like a non-const optional).

You can use this to "iterate" over the optional:

```
for (auto const& v: IterateOpt{function_call()}) {
  do_smth(v);
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like

```
for (const auto& x : optionalValue.value()){
    //code
}
```

this can throw `std::bad_optional_access`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211004-00/?p=105754